# How to do deal with varying performance across a wide range of parameters?

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, optimization, model-selection, hyperparameter

We are working on a recommendation system. Our data comes from varying sources that make it natural to train a model for each source. Now we come to the crux. For each of the data sources we get varying performance for

- the used model: random forest, ridge regression, association rule
  mining, xgboost
- the hyperparameters of the chosen model: alpha, number of estimators etc.
- parameters for how the data is fed into the model like: window size or relearn interval

Unfortunately there seems to be no combination that works best for all our data sources. In the end this forces us to train with all combinations for each data source to get the best performance. Now we are wondering if there is a way out of this computational mess.

Edit: The reason why a different model for every source seems reasonable, is that the different sources lead to mostly non-overlapping feature sets and recommendation options.

Comment: Could you be more specific on the reasons why you cannot pool all the data sources and use them together to train models?

Comment: @user4422 We just tested pooling the data from multiple sources and training a combined model. We like the idea, because even though it increases the model training time (for fixed parameters) and reduces the scores by a bit, it decreases the parameter search space by one dimension.

Comment: IIUC, you have for each source a model, and those models differ from source to source. But you want a model that works well for all sources? But it must not be a mixture of experts of those individual models? Why not?

Comment: @frank we are not necessarily against a mixture of experts. We found ourselves finding more and more models, therefore more and more parameters, that all seem to be helping push the score for one or the other data source. With this growing approach however we get more and more computation to do. So we were wondering if there is a way to stop this computational grow by for instance focusing on a single model. But the problem is that the single model does not get the best score for every data source. So we are basically stuck with testing through every combination to get the best score it seems.

Comment: How are you measuring the performance of these? It sounds a bit odd to me that you would be just trying arbitrary things and seeing performance improve consistently.

Comment: @kqr We have been using the MAP@4 score (4 because there is only enough space for about 4 recommendations in the UI). The definition of it, you can find [here](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/h-and-m-personalized-fashion-recommendations/overview/evaluation). Earlier we used scores with fixed cutoff, but now we prefer this one, because it averages over multiple cutoffs. Btw. we are not participating at the linked competition we are just adopting the scoring.